# {Python} Generate unique integers using iteration

Tags: python, random, iteration

I'm making a program to collect information from the user, and to add it to a text file.
It's a program that will be used to get said information from a number of applicants.
For linearity in the results I collect, I want to randomly ask the questions.

What i'm asking is a way to pull a question from the list, ask for input, store the input in the text file, and then ask another question pulled from the list at random.
Here is my code so far:

```
def ques():
global quesnum
for i in questions:
    num = int(random.randint(0,len(questions)-1))
    j = int(numbers.count(str(num)))
    while j >= 1:
        num = int(random.randint(0,len(questions)-1))
        ##DEBUG ONLY##
        print('true')
        break
    else:
        num = str(num)
        numbers.append(num)
        ##DEBUG ONLY##
        print('false')
    num = int(num)
    answer = input(str(quesnum) + '. ' + questions[num] + ': ')
    answers.write(str(quesnum) + '. ' + questions[num] + ': ')
    answers.write(answer + '\n')
    quesnum = int(quesnum + 1)
```

**Errors:**

Once the number has been used it is added to the list.
If a number has already been used, ideal situation is to generate a new number and use that instead.
I can't see any errors in my code, and as far as I can see it should work fine.
Can anyone point out a fix or suggest a better way of doing this? I have already found answers suggesting to use `random.sample()` but I have tried this already and can't get that working either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would strongly recommend against using `global`, if a function needs a value pass it in as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by using `random.shuffle`:

```
import random

questions = ['Q1: ...', 'Q2: ...', 'Q3: ...']
random.shuffle(questions)
for q in questions:
    answer = raw_input(q + ': ')
    with open("answers.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write("{}: {}\n\n".format(q, answer))
```

This will shuffle your questions, ask them in random order and save them to a text file. If you want to save more detailed information for each question, this will also work with a list of dicts. E.g.

```
questions = [
    {'nr.': 1, 'text': 'Do you like horses?'},
    {'nr.': 2, 'text': 'Where were you born?'}
]
```

Comment: Okay. So will `random.shuffle()` change the order of my list, and then I can simply ask them using `for i in questions: answer = input(questions[])`?

Comment: Correct. `random.suffle()` will change the order every time you call it. As long as you call it *before* iterating over them, you will get a different order.